# Anchor is across all page and not only on the text

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'm currently trying to make my main page look better and beeing easier to download on slow internet.

Previously I used images as text, and that makes it slow to load.
Now I'm trying to use real text. The problem is that the anchor spans across the full width of the page and not only the text.

Link to page:
http://www.hoppvader.nu/index2.php

How can I make the link "stop" at the end of the text but still make the text overflow on line two as display: block; does?
The current setup works fine on small devices as phones but the problem is the anchor expands too far.

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Klubb";
    src: url(Manifest/sys/MonotypeCorsiva.ttf) format("truetype");
}
span.Klubb { /* Text link */
        font-family: 'Klubb', Verdana, Tahoma;
        font-size: 3.5vw;   
        font-weight: 900;
        text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px #FF0000;
        color: black;
        display: block;
        padding-left: 150px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        margin-top:0px;
        padding-bottom:20px;
    }
span.pLogga { /* Image on the left of text */
        float: left;
        width: 160px;
        text-align: center;
        }
```

Sample html:

```
<span><a Style='text-decoration:none' href=UFK-Skelleftea.php><span class='pLogga'><img src=../Manifest/sys/Logga/UFK.gif alt='Umeå Skellefteå' height=50/></span><span class='Klubb'>Umeå fallskärmsklubb (Skellefteå)</span></a></span><br>
<span><a Style='text-decoration:none' href=UFK-Umea.php><span class='pLogga'><img src=../Manifest/sys/Logga/UFK.gif alt='Umeå fallskärmsklubb Umeå' height=50/></span><span class='Klubb'>Umeå fallskärmsklubb (Umeå)</span></a></span><br>
```

Comment: because all the elements are block level, wherever you have used `display:block;` make it `display: inline-block;`

Comment: I tried that now. And as long as the window is in full screen it works, but if I resize the window to smaler it goes crazy.

Comment: your markup is messy. You need to make it clean. Make use of floats.

Comment: I think that is what I did now. outer span is now style float left and it seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest making the outer span display: block, clear: left. Add float: left to the .klubb span and then reduce the padding/margin on it.

Comment: What is clear left? I think the code is as you say now except the clear left.

Comment: clear is a css property that will make sure your floats stack instead of displaying horizontally across the page, 'clear eachother'. You can either clear items to the left or right. Very useful when using floated items.

Comment: Ahh... So that is why it's placing themselfs next to each other in full screen mode? :-) thx! :-)

Comment: Yep! No problem :)

Comment: Something is not right. If you narrow the width of the screen, vertical mode of phone. The text goes below the image. I want the text to wordwrap next to the image